# Installing LLReve using Cmake. Unknown BISON_TARGET error

Tags: cmake, bison

I am getting the following error :

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (BISON_TARGET):
  Unknown CMake command "BISON_TARGET".
```

when I run the command :

```
 cmake .. -GNinja
```

Please tell me what to do. I tried searching on google a lot and thus came up with the additions and finally ran the command :

```
cmake .. -D LLVM_DIR=/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/cmake/ -D FLEX_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/Cellar/flex/2.5.37/bin/ -D FLEX_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/flex/2.5.37/include/ -D BISON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/bison
```

but it still shows the same error :(.

Please someone help.

Comment: `BISON_TARGET` is supplied by the `FindBison` package which the top-level CMake includes. Are you trying to build one of the subdirectories by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is occurring because the `BISON_TARGET` function definition has not yet been supplied. This method, as commented, is supplied by [`FindBISON`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBISON.html). The error indicates that either Bison was not found on your system (hopefully, you have it installed), or `cmake` was ran from the wrong directory. Bison is included in the **top-level** CMake file via:

```
find_package(BISON REQUIRED)
```

This line to include Bison must be called before using the `BISON_TARGET` CMake function. The LLReve [instructions](https://github.com/mattulbrich/llreve/tree/7210d07fe4786b286b76c93c5265584d728922ac/reve/reve#compilation) for compiling this repository are explicit about which directory to run the build commands in:

> Go to the llreve directory and run
>
> ```
> cd reve
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake .. -GNinja
> ninja
> ```

This would run on the CMake file in the `llreve/reve` directory, *not* the `llreve/reve/reve` directory. Please ensure you are running CMake from the correct location, as not running `cmake` on the **top-level** CMake file will often yield errors.